# Drawing Tree with one circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Good Evening,
how can I draw this graph with another edge between b and c?
***using overleaf***

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The simplest would be using `tikz-cd`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest `tikz-cd`. Here's how it works.  First place your nodes as you would make a matrix, except in a `tikzcd`. The `&` symbol separated nodes in the same row. `\\` signals to move to the next row.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
   & (a)\\
  (b) & & (c)\\
  (d)
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Then add arrows. In your case, the arrows don't have arrowheads, so the style is `-`. The syntax is `\arrow[-,dl]` to draw an arrow (with style `-`) from the current node to the node that is down 1 and left 1. To draw an arrow from the current node to the node 2 to the right, use `\arrow[-,rr]`

[image]

The complete code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
&(a)\arrow[-,dl]\arrow[-,dr]\\
(b)\arrow[-,d]\arrow[-,rr] && (c)\\
(d)
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```